# Problemas para inserir registro em webapi(c#) com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-web-api

Boa tarde Estou com problema para inserir registro em um webapi .Net utilizando o javascript. O método get está funcionando normalmente, retornando as informações do webapi dentro de uma tabela. Porém não estou conseguindo inserir as informações no webapi. Verifando a console do chrome, não aparece erro.

Abaixo o código para a leitura do webapi e exibição e crud em uma página web:

```js
//carrega o corpo da tabela
var tbody = document.querySelector('table tbody');

//Função para cadastrar produtos na base Json
function Cadastrar() {

  var _nome = document.querySelector('#nome').value;
  var _categoria = document.querySelector('#categoria').value;
  var _unidade = document.querySelector('#unidade').value;
  var _fragancia = document.querySelector('#fragancia').value;
  var _cor = document.querySelector('#cor').value;
  var _poskit = document.querySelector('#poskit').value;
  var _posfrag = document.querySelector('#posfrag').value;
  var _quantidade = document.querySelector('#quantidade').value;
  var _preco = document.querySelector('#preco').value;

  //Variável para criar o Json
  var produto = {

    nome: _nome,
    categoria: _categoria,
    unidade: _unidade,
    fragancia: _fragancia,
    cor: _cor,
    possui_kit: _poskit,
    posui_fragancia: _posfrag,
    quantidade: _quantidade,
    preco: _preco
  }

  //Carrega produto, adicionando o produto novo.
  carregaProdutos('POST', 0, produto);
  //console.log(produto);

}

function Cancelar() {

  var btnSalvar = document.querySelector('#btnSalvar');
  var btnCancelar = document.querySelector('#btnCancelar');
  var titulo = document.querySelector('#titulo');

  btnSalvar.textContent = 'Cadastrar';
  btnCancelar.textContent = 'Limpar';

  titulo.textContent = 'Cadastrar Produtos';


}

/*

Função para carregar os produtos do webapi para a página web, através de 
um objeto ajax.
*/
function carregaProdutos(metodo, id, corpo) {

  //Limpa o body antes de carregar
  tbody.innerHTML = '';


  //Objeto utilizado para criar o Ajax
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  //Se tipo e valor forem indefinidos, id receberá vazio
  if (id === undefined || id === 0)
    id = '';

  /*

         -> Configuração do Ajax
         GET -> Informa o método GET no HTTP
         '' -> Url do WepApi
         true -> Indicando que a chamada será assícrona

        */
  xhr.open('GET', `http://localhost:51722/api/Produtos/${id}`, true);

  /*Ao carregar o ajax, será executado uma função anônima,
  exibindo a resposta no console.lo
  */
  xhr.onload = function() {
    /*Converte para json e armazena na varíavel as informações
    obtidas através do webapi_produtos*/
    var produtos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    /*Varre todo objeto json vindo do webapi, adicionando linhas
    através da função adicionar linhas
    */
    for (var indice in produtos) {
      adicionaLinha(produtos[indice]);
    }
  }
  /*Se o parametro corpo for diferente de indefinido, a função irá obteratravés do json informado,no qual será convertido para texto
   */
  if (corpo !== undefined) {
    //Informa o tipo de header
    xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    //Converte o arquivo JSON para text
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(corpo));
  } else {

    //Executa a chamada a função
    xhr.send();

  }

}

carregaProdutos('GET');


//Função para editar produtos na tabela
function editarProduto(produto) {

  var btnSalvar = document.querySelector('#btnSalvar');
  var btnCancelar = document.querySelector('#btnCancelar');
  var titulo = document.querySelector('#titulo');
  var _nome = document.querySelector('#nome').value;
  var _categoria = document.querySelector('#categoria').value;
  var _unidade = document.querySelector('#unidade').value;
  var _fragancia = document.querySelector('#fragancia').value;
  var _cor = document.querySelector('#cor').value;
  var _poskit = document.querySelector('#poskit').value;
  var _posfrag = document.querySelector('#posfrag').value;
  var _quantidade = document.querySelector('#quantidade').value;
  var _preco = document.querySelector('#preco').value;


  btnSalvar.textContent = 'Salvar';
  btnCancelar.textContent = 'Cancelar';

  titulo.textContent = `Editar Produto - ${produto.nome}`;



  console.log(produto);
}


//Função para adiciona linhas na tabela
function adicionaLinha(produto) {





  var trow = `<tr>
       <td>${produto.nome}</td>
       <td>${produto.categoria}</td>
       <td>${produto.unidade}</td>
       <td>${produto.fragancia}</td>
       <td>${produto.cor}</td>
       <td>${produto.possuiKit}</td>
       <td>${produto.possuiFragancia}</td>
       <td>${produto.quantidadeKit}</td>
       <td>${produto.preco}</td>
       <td><button onclick='editarProduto(${JSON.stringify(produto)})'>Editar</button></td>
      </tr>
      `

  //Adciona o conteudo da variável trow na tabela
  tbody.innerHTML += trow;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE htm>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h2 id="titulo">Cadastrar Produtos</h2>
  <hr>
  <div><label>Nome:</label><input id="nome" type="text"></div>
  <div><label>Categoria:</label>
    <select id="categoria">

      <option value="Cloro e Desinfetante">Cloro e Desinfetente</option>
      <option value="Saco de Lixo">Saco de Lixo</option>
      <option value="Panos e Flanelas">Panos e Flanelas</option>
      <option value="Esponja">Esponja</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div><label>Unidade:</label><input id="unidade" type="text"></div>
  <div><label>Fragância:</label>
    <select id="fragancia">

      <option value="">Não possui fragância</option>
      <option value="frutas vermelhas">frutas vermelhas</option>
      <option value="palmolive">palmolive</option>
      <option value="caiaque">caiaque</option>
      <option value="talco">talco</option>
      <option value="erva doce">erva doce</option>
      <option value="opus">opus</option>
      <option value="pinho">pinho</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div><label>Cor:</label>
    <select id="cor">

      <option value="">Não possui cor</option>
      <option value="rosa">rosa</option>
      <option value="lilas">lilas</option>
      <option value="azul bebê">azul bebê</option>
      <option value="branco">branco</option>
      <option value="verde">verde</option>
      <option value="amarelo">amarelo</option>
      <option value="rosa choque">rosa choque</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form>
      <label>Possui Kit ?:</label>
      <label>Sim</label><input type="radio" id="poskit" name="possui kit" value=true>
      <label>Não</label><input type="radio" id="poskit" name="possui kit" value=false checked>
    </form>

  </div>
  <div>
    <form>
      <label>Possui Fragância ?:</label>
      <label>Sim</label><input type="radio" id="posfrag" name="possui fragancia" value=true>
      <label>Não</label><input type="radio" id="posfrag" name="possui fragancia" value=false checked>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div><label>Quantidade Kit:</label><input id="quantidade" type="text"></div>
  <div><label>Preço:</label><input id="preco" type="text"></div>
  <div>
    <button id="btnSalvar" onclick="Cadastrar()">Cadastrar</button>
    <button id="btnCancelar" onclick="Cancelar()">Limpar</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Categoria</td>
        <td>Unidade</td>
        <td>Fragância</td>
        <td>Cor</td>
        <td>Possui Kit?</td>
        <td>Possui Fragância</td>
        <td>Quantidade</td>
        <td>Preço</td>
        <td>Opções</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Abaixo, a tela html:

[image: Tela com a interface html / javascript]

Comment: Boa tarde, poderia informar qual é a URL onde o front end está hospedado?

Answer (score 0):

O que está ocorrendo é, como o seu front está hospedado em um local diferente do seu serviço, o [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS)(Cross-origin resource sharing) do serviço está bloqueando o Origin do seu front end, será necessário Configurar o CORS no Startup do seu serviço da seguinte forma (.NET Core):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var URLsCORS = new string[] 
    {
        "http://localhost"
    };
    app.UseCors(builder => 
    {
        builder.WithOrigins(URLsCORS).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
    });
}
```

Onde `URLsCORS` são as hospedagens que poderão enviar requisições com todos os métodos(GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc).

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme